# How to verify the response has at least one valid array data?

Tags: karate

I got a response like:

```
{
    "by_group": [
        {
            "key": "2021-03-17T00:00:00.000+08:00",
            "by_state": [
                {
                    "key": "STATE1",
                    "value": 1
                },
                {
                    "key": "STATE2",
                    "value": 2
                }
            ]
        },
                {
            "key": "2021-03-20T00:00:00.000+08:00",
            "by_state": [
                {
                    "key": "STATE3",
                    "value": 3
                },
                {
                    "key": "STATE4",
                    "value": 4
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "key": "2021-03-24T00:00:00.000+08:00",
            "by_state": []
        }
    ]
}
```

schema used here:

```
    * def schema2 = { key : '#string', value : '##number? _ >= 0' }
    * def schema1 = { key : '#string', by_state : '#[_ > 0] schema2' }
    And match response ==
    """
    {
      by_group: '#[_ > 0] schema1'
    }
    """
```

It failed when we got the 3rd item which was an empty array, but we allowed this to happen.

We just need to make sure there is at least one valid "by_state" array in the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement can be expressed as one line:

```
* match response.by_group contains { key: '#string', by_state: '#[_ > 0]' }
```

Note that `karate.filter()` is something you should be aware of. So you can filter out the elements you want, and then count the number of results returned etc: https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms